# ¿ Por qué tengo error actualizando valores con vue.js / laravel 5.2?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Hola, tengo un problema, esta semana inicie un proyecto con Laravel 5.2 y Vuejs, Tengo unas tarjetas con información y hasta el momento puedo traerlas de la base de datos y eliminar, ahora me encuentro con un problema al momento de actualizar cualquiera de ellas
Les comparto el codigo con vue

```js
Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');

var vm = new Vue({
 
  el: '#app-home',

  data: {
    mail:"usuario@server.net",
    tarjetas: [],
    tipo_cobro : 'cobro',
    tipo_recordatorio : 'recordatorio',
    tipo_anotacion : 'comentario',
    data_anotacion:[],
    data_recordatorio:[],
    data_cobro:[],
    id: "", mensaje: "",id_creador: "",fecha_cobro: "", fecha_vencimiento: "",
    serial: "",monto: "",estado: "",created_at: "",updated_at: "",fecha_inicio: "",
    involucrados: "",id_perfil: "",tipo_perfil: "",tipo_anotacion: "", comprobante: "",
    fecha_comentario: "",empresa_id: "",foto: "", nombre_comercial: "", fotografia: "",
    
    UpData : { _token: $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), mensaje : "", id_creador: "",
    fecha_cobro: "", serial: "",  monto: "",
    estado: "",  fecha_inicio: "",
    involucrados: "", id_perfil: "",
    tipo_anotacion: "", comprobante: "",
    fecha_comentario: ""
  }
  },
 methods: {
SetUpdate: function(){

  this.UpData.mensaje      = this.mensaje
  this.UpData.id_creador   = this.id_creador
  this.UpData.fecha_cobro  = this.fecha_cobro
  this.UpData.serial       = this.serial
  this.UpData.estado       = this.estado
  this.UpData.fecha_inicio = this.fecha_inicio
  this.UpData.involucrados = this.involucrados
  this.UpData.id_perfil    = this.id_perfil
  this.UpData.tipo_anotacion = this.tipo_anotacion
  this.UpData.comprobante  = this.comprobante
  this.UpData.fecha_comentario = this.fecha_comentario

  console.log(this.UpData)

},
UpdateCobro: function (){
  this.SetUpdate()
 var newDataCard = this.UpData;
  this.$http.patch('/card/' + this.id, newDataCard , function (data) {
console.log(data)  })
  this.load_notes()
},
load_notes: function () {
   this.$http.get('/card').then((data) => {
this.$set('anotaciones', data.json()),
this.tarjetas = data.json()
  })
 },
ready: function () {
  this.load_notes()
}
}
```

Etse es mi script y el problema ocurre cuando ejecuto ***UpdateCobro***
 [image]

La ruta:

```
Route::resource('card', 'ApiAsteroidController');
```

Esta es la función de Laravel para hacer el Update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    Anotacion::findOrFail($id)->update($request->all());
    return response()->json($request->all());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno algo parecido me sucedio a mi y era por problemas de las rutas, intenta cambiar tu ruta:

```
Route::get('/card/{id}', ['as' => 'card.update', 'uses'=>'ApiAsteroidController@update']);

$url = route('card.update', ['id' => 19]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes

Comment: Hola Elio, ¿te paso con vue?, yo estoy usando Route::resource , voy a probar y te cuento.

Comment: Si me paso con vue.js y también cuando envías información con ajax. Espero esto pueda solucionar tu problema. Suerte

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que `$request->all()` tambien contiende la variable `_token`, puede que te salte la excepción debido a que no puede actualizar ese valor. La solución sería utilizar:

`$request->except('_token')->all()`